# How to find the imagen of this set under the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the imagen of $R= \{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid|z-1|<1 \} $ under the tranformation $w=\frac{1}{z}$

I know that $R$ is a filled circle whit center in the point $1+0i$. But, i can't find a way to define the set for use the fact that $|w|=\frac{1}{|z|}$. 
I appreciate your help

Comment: You sure you have your set defined correctly?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Use \mid for the vertical bar :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams fixed

Comment: Have you learned about Möbius transformations (linear fractional transformations) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|<1\}$, and let $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by $f(z)={\large{\frac{1}{z}}}$.

The goal is to find $f(S)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&z\in f(S)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\frac{1}{z}\in S\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\left|\frac{1}{z}-1\right| < 1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\left|\frac{1}{z}-1\right|^{\,2} < 1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{\bar{z}}-1\right) < 1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(1-z)(1-\bar{z}) < z\bar{z}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&1-\bar{z}-z+z\bar{z} < z\bar{z}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&z+\bar{z} > 1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2} > \frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\text{Re}(z) > \frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]
&\text{hence}\\[4pt]
f(S)&=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re}(z) > \frac{1}{2}\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Alternatively, using the approach suggested by the user "Riemann",
\begin{align*} 
&\left|\frac{1}{z}-1\right| < 1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&|z-1| < |z|\\[4pt]
\iff\;&z\;\text{is closer to}\;1\;\text{than to}\;0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\text{Re}(z) > \frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]\end{align*}

Comment: $\left|\frac{1}{z}-1\right| < 1\iff|z-1|<|z|$ is enough!

Comment: @Riemann: Yes, that's much simpler.